# Checking multiple paths for existing file on server

Tags: c#, connection-timeout

I am writing a small application, which should check on a server if an installer of a software  is existing and if yes download to the file.

To do so, the application checks a website for the latest version number, e.g. `6.13.2.38` using *HtmlAgilityPack*.

The URL to this version is something like http://update.xyzsoftware.com/Files/Updates/6.13.2.38/xyzSoftware6_13_2_38_en_FullInstallerx64.exe.

Now I wrote a method, which loops through the last part of the version numbers to check if versions like
http://update.xyzsoftware.com/Files/Updates/6.13.2.38/xyzSoftware6_13_2_37_en_FullInstallerx64.exe
http://update.xyzsoftware.com/Files/Updates/6.13.2.38/xyzSoftware6_13_2_36_en_FullInstallerx64.exe

...
http://update.xyzsoftware.com/Files/Updates/6.13.2.38/xyzSoftware6_13_2_1_en_FullInstallerx64.exe

exist.

```
static string checkValidity(string urlToTest)
    {
        string validityResult = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlToTest));
        request.Method = "HEAD";

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;

                validityResult = Convert.ToString(status);

                response.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            validityResult = "not OK";
        }

        return validityResult;
    }
```

What I am experiencing now is the fact that I get the exception message for all tested urls. Trying to access the original (working) url in the browser tells me 
`The connection was reset`

At first I was scared and thought that I had shut down the server. But when I checked the address via an alternative internet connection, everything was ok.

What can be the reason for this? Perhaps the local router / firewall, the DNS server, or the remote server?

What can I do to avoid this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Comment: *"I get the exception message"* - What exception do you get?

Comment: I try to translate the exception, as I use the german version of Visual Studio 2019:

   *The underlying connection was closed: Unknown error in receiving.

System.IO.IOException: No data can be read from the transmission connection: An existing connection was closed by the remote host.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was closed by the remote host.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is a fairly terrible way to do your update provision. You seem to be saying that the software will increment numbers and keep trying URLs until it gets one that isn't 404

You'd be better off having one fixed URL:

```
http://update.xyzsoftware.com/version/latest/SomeSoftwareName
```

That does a lookup of what the current version of that software is and returns a response:

```
class VersionController{

  public ActionResult Latest(string appname){
    //lookup version number of appname
    var ver = dbContext.Versions.Where(v => v.AppName == appname).OrderByDescending(v => v.VersionAsFloat).First();

    return Json(new { Version = ver.VersionAsFloat, Url = ver.Url });

  }
}
```

Consume the emitted JSON on the client side, use the Version give to work out if the remote version is higher than the local, and if so download the update from the given URL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not want to achieve to have an update provisioning with the tool, but a possibility to download older versions of the software. As I do not know all the older version numbers, my idea was to loop through all possible version numbers and check for each, if such a file exists on the server.

Comment: @Gardinero your better off pulling a manifest json (or even xml) listing all the available versions and related urls

Comment: @Gardinero then my advice still holds true, but instead of returning one record in the update check, turn it into an array of versions and call it a "get available versions" check or something..